# Scikit Learn Variable Bias

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using Scikit to make some prediction on a very large set of data. The data is very wide, but not very long so I want to set some weights to the parts of the data. If I know some parts of the data are more important then other parts how should I inform SCikit of this, or does it kinda break the whole machine learning approach to do some pre-teaching.

Comment: It all depends on the data. Since you are not being very informative about its nature nor posting any example, the people that are trying to help you with the already provided answers are more or less groping around in the dark ...

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way of doing this is perhaps by using [Principal Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) on your data matrix X. Principal vectors form an orthogonal basis of X, and they are each one a linear combination of the original feature space (normally columns) of X. The decomposition is such that each principal vector has a corresponding eigenvalue (or singular value depending on how you compute PCA) a scalar that reflects how much reconstruction can be made solely on the basis of that principal vector alone, in a least-squares sense.

The magnitude of coefficients of principal vectors can be interpreted as importance of the individual features of your data, since each coefficient maps 1:1 to a feature or column of the matrix. By selecting one or two principal vectors and examining their magnitudes, you may have a preliminary insight of what columns are more relevant, of course up to how much these vectors approximate the matrix.

[This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) is the detailed scikit-learn API description. Again, PCA is a simple but just one way of doing it, among others.

Answer (score 1):

This probably depends a bit on the machine learning algorithm you're using -- many will discover feature importances on their own (as elaborated via the `feature_importances_` property in random forest and others).

If you're using a distance-based measure (e.g. k-means, knn) you could manually weight the features differently by scaling the values of each feature accordingly (though it's possible scikit does some normalization...).

Alternatively, if you know some features really don't carry much information you could simply eliminate them, though you'd lose any diagnostic value these features might unexpectedly bring. There are some tools in scikit for [feature selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) that might help make this kind of judgement.